# how to slice array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that needs to be sliced into the following format.

```
$arr = [val1, val2, val3, val4, ...];

$result = [

        [ val1, val2, val3 ], /* first 3 elements */
        [ val4, val5, val6 ], /* next 3 elements */
        
        [ val7 ], /* next 1 element */
        [ val8 ], /* next 1 element */
        
        [ val9, val10], /* next 2 elements */
        [ val11, val12 ], /* next 2 elements */ 


        [ val13, val14, val15 ], /* next 3 elements */
        [ val16, val17, val18 ], /* next 3 elements */
        
        [ val19 ], /* next 1 element */
        [ val20 ], /* next 1 element */
        
        [ val21, val22], /* next 2 elements */
        [ val23, val24 ], /* next 2 elements */
        
        /*repeat same with next (3,3,1,1,2,2) elements */
        
];
```

Comment: $arr = []
$format = [3,3,1,1,2,2];
I did in loop but how to do N time.

Comment: Are there always multiples of 12 `var`'s in the original array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code does what you want:

```
$arr = range(1, 30);
$spreads = [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2];
$result = [];
while (true) {
    foreach ($spreads as $spread) {
        if (count($arr) == 0) break 2; // in a function return $result instead
        $result[] = array_splice($arr, 0, $spread);
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

This removes portions according to `$spreads` from `$arr` using [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) until the array is empty. Note that the original array is mutated, so you might want to operate on a copy (`$copy = $arr`).

Comment: Could be worth adding some explanation.

Comment: Nice and simple, but it should be mentioned, that the original array is mutated and empty and the end.

Answer (score 2):

Just use while loop and iterate over the data. You can use the pattern as a repeatable counter.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mnfhP

```
$pattern = [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2];
$data = range(1, 40);

$patternValue = current($pattern);
$patternCount = 0;

$result = [];
$row = [];
while ($value = current($data)) {
    if ($patternCount === $patternValue) {
        $patternValue = next($pattern);
        if (false === $patternValue) {
            $patternValue = reset($pattern);
        }
        $patternCount = 0;
        $result[] = $row;
        $row = [];
    }
    $row[] = $value;
    $patternCount++;
    next($data);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7],[8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19],[20],[21,22],[23,24],[25,26,27],[28,29,30],[31],[32],[33,34],[35,36],[37,38,39]]

Comment: One thing I noticed is that doesn't include 40.

Comment: Yes, it does not fit into the pattern. Maybe there's only 1-39. OP did not define it, so I was lazy taking any range.

Answer (score 1):

This solution breaks the original data into chunks according to the sum of all of the individual bits.  Then for each chunk - it again splits it down.

Although there are nested loops, it's operating on chunks of data and not individual elements.

```
$pattern = [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2];
$data = range(1, 40);

// How many elements to take each chunk
$length = array_sum($pattern);
// Split the start data into segments
$chunks = array_chunk($data, $length);

$output = [];
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // For each chunk
    $offset = 0;
    foreach ($pattern as $nextChunkSize) {
        // If no more data, exit loop
        if ($offset > count($chunk)) {
            break;
        }
        // Extract the part of the array for this particular bit
        $output[] = array_slice($chunk, $offset, $nextChunkSize);
        // Move start on by amount of data extracted
        $offset += $nextChunkSize;
    }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

gives...
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7],[8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19],[20],[21,22],[23,24],[25,26,27],[28,29,30],[31],[32],[33,34],[35,36],[37,38,39],[40]]

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = range(0, 50);
$chunks = [ 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2 ];

$pattern = [];
$chunkCount = count($chunks);
for($i = 0; $i < $chunkCount; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < $chunks[$i]; $j++) {
    $pattern[] = $i;
  }
}

// $pattern is now: [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 ]

$result = [];
$patternCount = count($pattern);
$inputCount = count($input);
for($i = 0; $i < ceil($inputCount / $patternCount); $i++) {
  for($j = 0; $j < $patternCount; $j++) {
    $index = $i * $patternCount + $j;
    if ($index > $inputCount - 1) {
      break 2;
    }
    $result[$i * $chunkCount + $pattern[$j]][] = $input[$index];
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 23
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 26
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 29
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 33
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34
            [1] => 35
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 37
            [2] => 38
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 41
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44
            [1] => 45
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [1] => 47
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 48
            [1] => 49
            [2] => 50
        )

)
```